# Nuxtjs: How to call component inside another component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I understand paradigm "Page-component" but what if I have a page that renders component, how do I call another component inside this component? Currently nuxtjs does not allow me do it. I can not stick to standart "page-component" scheme as I am bulding cart which calls cart-items.

Say If a cart component which is called by page looks like this, how would it call cart-item component inside it?

```
<!---- cart component called from index.vue --->

    <template>
        <div>
            <Cart-item></Cart-item> < ---------- This doesn't work.
        </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
        props: ['items']
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed it the standard way:

```
<template>
        <div>
            <CartItem></CartItem>
        </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import CartItem from  '../components/Cart-item'
    export default {
        props: ['items']
    }
    </script>
```

Since nuxtjs auto-registers all components wonder if there is more graceful way.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: as promised, here is an example on how to pass some content to a component from another one thanks to `slots`. This is totally working in any Nuxt page ofc.

`NestedContent.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Here is the NestedContent component and below is a slot passed to ParentWithSlots' component</p>
    <hr />
    <parent-with-slots>
      <!-- <template #default> // this one can be omit since we do use the default slot here -->
      <p>This content is inserted into the component ParentWithSlots</p>
      <!-- </template> -->
    </parent-with-slots>
  </div>
</template>
```

`ParentWithSlots.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>xxxxxxxxxxx ParentWithSlots' content before slot xxxxxxxxxxx</p>
    <slot>Default content in case none is provided</slot>
    <p>xxxxxxxxxxx ParentWithSlots' content after slot xxxxxxxxxxx</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is how it looks [image]

PS: you may also give a try to [layouts](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/views#custom-layout), it can be useful for overall positioning of some of your components visually.

---

If your components are in the `components` directory, you can set `components: true` in your `nuxt.config.js` and have access to it pretty much anywhere without any additional step with the `<cart-item></cart-item>` syntax.

More details here: https://nuxtjs.org/blog/improve-your-developer-experience-with-nuxt-components/